# Android Visualizer on muted AudioTrack/MediaPlayer

Tags: android, pcm, mute, visualizer

I have a PCM-stream which I would like to visualize with Android's "Visualizer" but without playing it out loudly.

Therefor I have implemented [android-visualizer](https://github.com/felixpalmer/android-visualizer).

The visualization is successful, if I use

```
audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 44100,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
            fileContent.length, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
audioTrack.play();
mVisualizerView.link(audioTrack);
..
audioTrack.write(fileContent, 0, bytes);
```

But now my problem is, that I don't want to really "play" my PCM, I just would like to visualize it. My users are maybe hearing music with their media-player and I don't want to disturb them.

So I thought 'ok, I can just mute my AudioTrack':

```
audioTrack.setStereoVolume(0.0f, 0.0f);
```

but sadly there's also no more visualization.
I thought that the Visializer should ignore the loudness of the AudioTrack due to [SCALING_MODE_NORMALIZED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Visualizer.html#SCALING_MODE_NORMALIZED) :

> Defines a capture mode where amplification is applied based on the
>   content of the captured data. This is the default Visualizer mode, and
>   is suitable for music visualization.

The next I tried was not writing the PCM into the audio-track, but providing it directly to the drawer:

```
mVisualizerView.updateVisualizer(fileContent);
```

That creates a curve, but it looked really crazy and has nothing to do with that what I expected (maybe because I'm providing stereo instead of mono?).

I also had no success with creating the "waveform" or the "fft"-data of the PCM-stream - I just to new to me.

Has anyone an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try AudioManager.setStreamMute(streamType, state)

Comment: I don't see how that would help, since this toggles the stream volume between 0 and some other value. The `AudioFlinger` takes track volume, stream volume and master volume into account when calculating the final volume. So this method would not achieve what the OP wants (to get non-zero data into the `Visualizer`, but without the audio being heard).

Answer (score 0):

> So I thought 'ok, I can just mute my AudioTrack'. but sadly there's also no more visualization.

That's just the way it works. The `AudioFlinger` performs mixing (where volume is applied) before applying effects (the `Visualizer` is an effect).

But you don't really need the `Visualizer` API for what you want to do, as you've already realized. You can create a canvas or OpenGL ES texture, draw some data based on your PCM data every frame (60 fps), and show it in one of your app's views.

If you just want to plot the waveform this would be trivial. Let's say that you've got a bitmap 100 pixels wide that you want to draw to: At frame `N` you'd take the 735 (44100/60) samples starting at N*735 and generate 100 points out of those (e.g. by linearly interpolating over those 735 samples, and scaling them according to the vertical resolution of your bitmap). If your PCM data is stereo you can take each pair of samples at the interpolation points and averaging them.

If you want to draw a [spectrogram](http://us.123rf.com/400wm/400/400/alinoubigh/alinoubigh0903/alinoubigh090300134/4503401-3d-illustration-of-spectrogram-and-audio-equalizer.jpg) things will get a bit more complicated, since you'd first have to transform your audio data from the time domain to [the frequency domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform).

Comment: To the downvoter: care to explain in what way this answer wasn't useful?